# From time to time I am getting error Error Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

When working on project (ASP.NET MVC web application) in VS2013 I am FROM TIME TO TIME getting error

> Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'.

After clicking on it the web.config from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config opens and shows a line:

```
<add extension=".edmx" 
     type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
```

Error occurs when I hit F5 or F6. I get a message - Build unsuccessful and a pop-up window appears if I want to run previous successfull build. I can ignore the message and the website starts normally.

What is really strange - sometimes there is no error and the application behaves normally.

I tried to add assembly to the web.config of the application - there is no difference.

Could you please help me with this annoying issue?

Comment: The line adds a build provider for websites. It is being used by websites to split the edmx to csdl, ssdl and msl. It's unclear from your description where/when the error pops up - at runtime or at design time. Is your application a website? What's the stack trace? Without these details it is impossible to tell anything.

Comment: I've added some additional info...

Comment: Have you tried removing this line from the config? I believe build providers are used only for web site projects and not for web applications and therefore it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I though about it but I do not really want to mess around with the files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\. There must be another way. I may be wrong though...

I've tried to delete this line just for a while - it did not help...

Comment: oh. I thought you said you had this line in the web.config... I agree it's better not to remove it from the machine.config.

Comment: I inherited an EF 6 project and I get this error if I try to turn on 'MVCBuildViews'